# How do we know the dimension of this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I read somewhere that this particular vector space,$$M(A,\alpha):=\{v\in F^n \mid (A-\alpha I_n)^nv=0\},$$ where $F$ is the splitting field for the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $F^n$ is the vector space containing all column vectors of length $n$, has dimension equivalent to the algebraic multiplicity of $\alpha$ as an eigenvalue of $A$.

Can someone explain how this thing happened? I'm quite a newbie in stuffs like this. Thank you very much for those who would gladly help.

Answer (score 0):

$M(A,\alpha)$ is called the *generalised eigenspace* for the eigenvalue $\alpha$. It is in fact equal to $\text{Ker} (A-\alpha\text{Id})^d$ where $d$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\alpha$.

One reason why its dimension is $d$ is that $F^n$ can be proved to be the direct sum of all generalised eigenspaces, and that each of them has dimension at most equal to the corresponding algebraic multiplicity. Therefore all of these inequalities are equalities for dimensional reasons.

Another way to see it is that in these settings, $A$ has a *Jordan normal form*, i.e. is similar to a triangular matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal, ones just above the diagonal, and zeroes elsewhere. From there the result is pretty easy.

---

**Digression.**

If you start from a vector $v$ and apply $A-\alpha\text{Id}$ once, then if you get $0$ it means that $v$ is an $\alpha$-eigenvector. But if you *don't* get $0$ you can iterate this process; if you get $0$ at the second iteration it means that in restriction to the $2$-dimensional space $\left<v, (A-\alpha\text{Id})v\right>$, with these basis vectors, the matrix of $A$ is $$\left(\matrix{\alpha & 0\\1&\alpha}\right)$$
This is the baby case of a *Jordan block*.

Note that I'm not saying that you *will* get $0$ eventually no matter which vector you started from. You will only if you started from a vector that does lie in $M(A,\alpha)$.

Comment: Usually, the vectors in this basis are taken in the reverse order, so the $1$ be *above* the diagonal.

Comment: @Bernard True. Here it seemed more natural to keep them in the order they appeared in the speech - it makes no real difference anyway.

Comment: How do we show that $F^n$ is in fact the direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces?

Comment: How do we know that the intersection of the generalized eigenspaces is only the zero vector?

Comment: @JBTemones You prove that when $P$ and $Q$ are coprime polynomials, $\text{Ker}((PQ)(A))=\text{Ker}(P(A))\oplus\text{Ker}(Q(A))$ - then use induction.